# What is the difference in power consumption between thermocouple and thermistor?

Tags: temperature, thermistor, thermocouple

I am working on a project to transmit sensor data and I chose to go with a temperature sensor to connect to a micro-controller.

Since I care a lot about power consumption for my project, I would like to know which is less power-consuming a thermocouple or a thermistor. Is there a way to connect one of them so it is more efficient than the other?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the two types in a circuit to get a measurement of temperature? Compared datasheets?

Comment: A thermisor needs power but a thermocouple needs an amplifier which needs power.

Comment: Hi @winny,
I have not. I am asking in general which can provide me the least power conumption possible?

Comment: They are very different. Did you know a thermocouple only measures temperature *differences*? To measure actual temperature you need another sensor at one end: "cold junction compensation".

Comment: What does your research tell you so far?

Comment: What are you measuring?  In other words, what's the overall application?  How frequently are you going to make measurements?  In general, there's not a lot of merit in comparing just the sensors by themselves, as @JRE has mentioned already.  It's likely that the choice of sensors will be dictated by other aspects: temperature range, cost, and so on.  Unless this is an academic question.

Comment: A thermocouple's power dissipation is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much point in comparing the power consumption of just the sensors.

A [thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) requires that you send a small current through it to measure the temperature.  The resistance of the thermistor changes with temperature.  A device to measure the temperature with a thermistor is an ohmmeter with some additional math.

A [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) generates a voltage proportional to the temperature - is produces current instead of consuming it like the thermistor.  A device to measure temperature with a thermocouple is a (very) sensitive voltmeter with some additional math.

The difference is that the signal is much stronger from a thermistor than a thermocouple.

A typical thermistor changes resistance enough that a 10 bit analog to digital converter (ADC) from a microprocessor (voltage resolution of 5 millivolts or so) can easily make 1 degree temperature measurements.

A typical K-type thermocouple changes its output voltage by only some 40 microvolts per degree.  The ADC of a typical microprocessor can't easily measure voltage changes that small.  You'll have to use a different ADC or an analog circuit to amplifiy the signal before digitalizing it.  You might also look at using a purpose built IC, or a thermocouple module that includes all the pre-processing and delivers a digital value to the microprocessor.

While the thermocouple actually generate power, using it can easily consume more power than the thermistor "wastes."

It isn't just the sensor you have to look at.  You have to consider the circuitry around the sensor.

Comment: A thermocouple generates a voltage proportional to a temperature difference, which means you need to measure the absolute temperature at the connection, so you'd at least need to use the built in temperature sensor of the µC - which usually don't provide very precise values, but depending on the requirements it might be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You ought to consider your total system power budget and allocate 1% or less to the sensor voltage and power required over your range of detection.

If that was hypothetically 10mW total then how can you choose a thermal sensing solution that uses 0.1mW? This is a hypothetical problem to solve but unless this just a thermostat makes you think about what % budget vs all the tasks such as driving a furnace reed relay switch, you ought to consider for a battery powered device with an LCD and make the battery last several years.

This study by [Mitsubishi](https://www.mmc.co.jp/adv/dev/english/document/thermistor/thermistor01.html) defines the sensitivity of thermistors by various constants.

The dissipation constant (δ) indicates the power necessary for increasing the temperature of the thermistor element by 1˚C through self-heating in a heat equilibrium.  Reducing this power requires low power voltage amplification with CMOS Op Amps and noise filtering to achieve low standard deviation in results.

Answer (score 1):

A thermocouple (e.g. J type) generates a voltage. A (passive) thermistor, on the other hand, changes its resistance depending on its type (i.e. PTC or NTC).

To get an accurate measurement, you need an active circuit for each.

- For thermocouples, you need to amplify the generated voltage (e.g. with an operational amplifier).
- For thermistors, you need a stable current source or you can use the thermistor as part of a voltage divider network *(NOTE: There are also active thermistor ICs like [this one](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP9700A). They generate an MCU-friendly voltage. But I'll keep them out of the scope for now)*.

> Since I care a lot about power consumption for my project, I would like to know which is less power-consuming of a thermocouple and a thermistor.

So it depends. Both solutions will consume power, but the amount of consumption depends on your implementation and needs.